# How do I add a scale bar or north arrow directly on the map control?

Tags: arcobjects

I've already looked into SurroundFrames and MapSurrounds, but this appears to be for cases in which you want to add these elements to a printed page. I, on the other hand, am using the MapControl within a live application, and I would like these element directly on the map, in the same way you see them on Google Maps.

Do I have to add these things from scratch using custom symbols and capturing events, or does ArcObjects automate this in any way?

Answer (score 1):

The PageLayoutControl is designed to do this.  Scale bars, legends, north arrow, map insets, titles, overview maps, etc. are all layout elements.